# Multiple Foreign Keys _ has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-keys, destroy

In Rails, I need a model to have a `has_many` with two foreign keys that need to be matched to make the list.

Ex:

**Organization_Profiles**

**table structure**

```
id : int
profile_id : int
organization_id : int
```

**associations**

```
belongs_to: :profile
belongs_to: :organization
has_many: :notifications, foreign_keys: [:profile_id, :organization_id], dependent: :destroy
```

**Notifications**

**table structure**

```
id : int
profile_id : int
organization_id : int
level : int
message : string
```

**associations**

```
belongs_to: :profile
belongs_to: :organization
```

How can I accomplish the above? From what I've researched, the `foreign_keys: []` does not exist.

Comment: What is the fundamental set of associations you need?  Let's consider rebuilding this to work for your needs.  Composite foreign keys are not ideal in Rails, and there is usually another solution.

Comment: @JoeEssey The above is the relationship I need. I need to be able to dependent: :destroy the notifications if an organization is removed from a user (i.e. a ProfileOrganization is destroyed.

Comment: I think you'll need to add a callback action to `ProfileOrganizations` to do the deletes then.  Then you won't need to build relationships to get the functionality of `dependent: :destroy`.  I don't know the full model of your app, but my instinct says there is something fishy with notifications being associated to a bridge table.

Comment: @JoeEssey The models are above (all they contain is the associations listed). When I remove an organization from a profile (essentially destroy a ProfileOrganization), I want all associated notifications to also be destroyed. If the way I propose is fishy, what would you suggest I try? I'm not sure of another way to accomplish this.

Comment: I misunderstood.  I have provided an answer that should work but will continue to think about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this without relying on the `dependent` command of an association.  The best way I can think of is to 'clean out' the associations when the action is taken to disassociate the `Profile` from an `Organization`.  You could have an inverse method in `Organization`.

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord:Base

  def method_that_disassociates_from(inputted_organization)
    self.organizations.delete(inputted_organization)
    self.notifications.where(organization_id: inputted_organization.id).destroy_all
  end

end
```

Comment: This works, but only if I call that method or use the route that calls that method. If I were to remove the ProfileOrganization without using that method/route, then the associations would remain. I believe placing similar code into an after_destroy on the ProfileOrganization should do the trick though.

Comment: I thought about putting the after_destroy in that class.  I guess you just do a `where(profile: profile, org: org).delete_all` query.  I didn't because I kind of feel like Notifications fundamentally belong to users and I'm unfairly asserting that bias on you  :).

Comment: Makes sense. The notifications are associated with a user, but in this case they are also associated with an organization, which is the functionality the join table provides. If you adjust your answer to account for that, I'll accept.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to do something similar for the very basic messaging feature of my app.

I have a Conversation model holding user1_id & user2_id, and each message has a user_id (for the sender) and a conversation_id (from which it can guess the recipient).

Ideally I would have just written something like:

```
  has_many :conversations, foreign_key: {:user1_id, :user2_id}, dependent: :destroy
```

I ended up redefining my own methods:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_destroy :delete_conversations

  def conversations
    Conversation.where('user1_id = :id OR user2_id = :id', id: id)
  end

  private

  def delete_conversations
    Conversation.where('user1_id = :id OR user2_id = :id', id: id).map(&:destroy)
  end
end
```